# Is there any way to hide the Airdrop option in the UIDocumentInteractionController sheet

Tags: ios, ios7.1, uidocumentinteraction, airdrop

I am using the UIDocumentInteractionController for sharing the files between apps. It works fine. But whenever I am opening the sheet , that sheet contains myapp + airdrop option.

Is there any way to hide the Airdrop option in the UIDocumentInteractionController sheet ?

THanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not in a way that is Apple Approved. Anything that hides/removes that button is going to be using private APIs or manipulating private views, both activities that will get your app rejected.